# Reading XML nodes causing issues

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have one XML string, I am trying to read that using C#, but I am not getting child nodes. I am getting entire XML as inner XML string. I am not able to read the nodes. Here is my XML string and my code.

```
<Filters FilterName="706337_test">
    <MemberName>Dorvil</MemberName>
    <MemberId />
    <ProviderName />
    <ProviderId>706337</ProviderId>
    <SelectedProjects>5030003</SelectedProjects>
    <CNAChartSelected>false</CNAChartSelected>
    <OldProject>false</OldProject>
</Filters>
```

C# code trying to read the XML nodes

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(xmlstring);
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Filters");
```

I can see only one child node that too filters, I need to read MemberId, MemberName etc., how to read them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your string in SelectNodes is wrong:

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(xmlstring);
var xnList1 = xml.SelectNodes("/Filters");      //list of 1 element
var xnList2 = xml.SelectNodes("/Filters/*");    //list of 7 elements
foreach (XmlNode node in xnList2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);
}
```

Also you can use this:

```
var xElements = XElement.Parse(xmlstring).Elements();
foreach (var element in xElements)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the app which nodes to read..

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
                    xml.LoadXml(xmlstring);

                    XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Filters");
foreach (XmlNode node in xnList)
{    
    string memberName = node["MemberName"].InnerText;
}
```

This lets the app know to read what is inside the MemberName node.. Do the same for the other nodes and post back your results. Debug as you go to see what you are getting out of each node.